# Probability of having $k$ sets containing two elements in a collection of sets of different size

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a finite set containing $m$ elements and let $\mathcal{C}$ be a finite collection of subsets of $\mathcal{X}$, potentially of different sizes. Given two elements $x_1 \in \mathcal{X}$ and $x_2 \in \mathcal{X}$, I am looking for the probability of having exactly $k$ subsets in $\mathcal{C}$ containing $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Assume that the sizes of the subsets in $\mathcal{C}$ is known, and that the subsets are taken uniformly at random among all possible subsets of a given size. Then, the probability for a subset of size $s$ of containing $x_1$ and $x_2$ is:
$$p_s = \frac{\binom{m - 2}{s - 2}}{\binom{m}{s}} = \frac{s(s - 1)}{m(m-1)}.$$
Then, the probability of having $r$ subsets of size $s$ containing $x_1$ and $x_2$ among $q$ subsets of size $s$ is:
$$\phi_s(q, r) = \binom{q}{r} p_s^r (1 - p_s)^{q - r}.$$
Now, if all subsets in $\mathcal{C}$ are of the same size, this answers my question. In the other case, I need to find a way to mix up binomial distribution with different parameters, which I do not know how to do.

Comment: Is there a typo in your formula for $p_s$? i.e. at the moment it does not depend on $s$. I think $k$ should be $s$ maybe?

Comment: Naively, this sounds hard. Do you have any context for the problem?

Comment: Obviously the probability strongly depends on the rules of building $\cal C$.

Comment: Indeed, there was a typo, I've corrected it thanks ! My context is the following: several voters have to vote on a set of candidates. They do so by submitting approval ballots indicating the candidates they approve of. These ballots can be of any size. Given an observed set of ballots, I'm looking at the probability of two candidates actually appearing $k$ times in the given ballot.